# Doctrine2 COUNT items while maintaining relationship of entities

Tags: php, symfony, count, doctrine-orm

I have three entities, FeedFolder, Feed and FeedItem

A FeedFolder has many Feeds
A Feed has many FeedItems

These relationships are defined on the entities.

I would like to get a count of FeedItems within each Feed, while maintaining the FeedFolder->Feed relationship too.

So ideally the return would be an array of FeedFolder, with each having their array of Feeds, and each feed would have a count of items.

```
<?php
$folders = [
    $feedFolder1...,
    $feedFolder2 => [
        'id' => 2,
        'feeds' => [
            $feed1...,
            $feed2 => [
                'id' => 2,
                'feedItemCount' => 23
            ]
        ]
    ]
];
```

I have tried a few things, the closest result I have is that each count comes back as a row containing the feed and folder name, so I can iterate this and get it back to the structure I'm expecting but really I would expect a way to do this using the Entity relationships.

```
<?php
$feedRepo->createQuery('
    SELECT ff.title, ff.id, f.name, f.id, COUNT(i) AS feedItemCount
    FROM MyFeedBundle:Feed f
    INNER JOIN f.feedFolder ff
    INNER JOIN ff.feedFolderUser u
    INNER JOIN f.feedItems i
    WHERE i.isRead = 0
    AND u.username = :username
    GROUP BY ff.id, f
    GROUP BY ff.title ASC, f.name ASC
');
```

(Notice there is also the join to user and filtering only unread items)

I went the queryBuilder route first, but that was harder to get this far in, either is fine with me of course though.